# User::find($id) doesn't work

Tags: sql, laravel, models

When I try `User::find($id)` to get user name with this function:

```
public function ShowUName()
    {
       $user = User::find(1);
       var_dump($user->user_name);
    }
```

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 1 limit 1)

but this one works good and return `user_name`:

```
public function ShowUName()
    {
        $users = User::where('user_id', '=', 1)->get();

        foreach ($users as $user)
        {
          var_dump($user->user_name);
        }
    }
```

I don't know where's the error with `find()`, any one can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to `User` model and

put,

```
protected $primaryKey = 'user_id';
```

may be your `User` model's primary key is `id` as default if u did not change. and seems like you change the primary key in the table to `user_id` so you need to specify the primary key as above to match with the actual table.

check the [laravel doc here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent)

Comment: its glad to help you :)